# Identification of plants

Tags: identification

Found these growing in our vegetable patch. Green leaves with red stems and central veins. We are in mid Michigan. Thank you[image: Picture of plants]

Answer (score 1):

I see a few smaller seedlings that are definitely cucurbits (squash/pumpkin/gourd/cucumber), but the large ones look different. The large plants  are taller and more vigorous than the cucurbits, so it's best to remove them. Otherwise they will out-compete the cucurbits for water and sunlight.

My default assumption is that any plant that "volunteers" in your garden that you don't recognize is a weed. If it was the seedling of something you had planted before and let go to seed, you would probably recognize it. But if you're curious, you could carefully dig them out and give them their own pot. Once they get a bit bigger it will be easier to figure out what they are. At this stage all the plants in this pot have fairly small root systems, so it should be possible to save most of the root system of the volunteer plants without hurting the roots of the cucurbits. Of course fill the holes back in with soil.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like squash / pumpkin / gourds. They are going to get way too big for that pot. Mabey  grow one in the pot .